# Add Quick Fix shortcut in Android Studio with Eclipse (Mac OS X) keymap

Tags: android-studio

I changed the my keymap settings in Android Studio Preferences to use Eclipse (Mac OS X). The shortcut <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>) does not work. I also can't see Quick Fix in the available actions. Help?

**Edit:**

It's listed under "Show Intention Actions". But trying to map it to <kbd>F2</kbd> shows this error.[image: error screenshot]

Comment: That error indicates that F2 is already mapped to something.  By default it is mapped to "Next Highlighted Error".  In Android Studio 2.2 it will say this outright.  Perhaps the image above is from an earlier version of AS that did not handle this situation as well.  You might want to map it to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

show intention actions at keymap